# Registering a DLL. When I need to register it in GAC?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

As title, In order to register a DLL, when I need to register it in GAC?

I simply took an old dll, decompiled with JetBrain, modified an URL (in Setting.cs) and recompiled.

Now I would substitute the old dll with this one and test if everything is good (so my site will be able to reach the new URL).

I ask you:

- I need to register it or I can just substiute the old dll ith this one?
- If I need to register it, I must register in GAC?

Thanks anyone for your support.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how the original one was deployed.  If this was in the GAC then so should your new one be, etc.

Comment: Well @Justin, how can I check if the original was registered in GAC?

Comment: since on the server there isn't visual studio how can I view a list of dll's in the GAC? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need VS, GacUtil is part of .Net

Comment: Seems o be strange since the message I return is: gacutil is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file .